# Вывод и заполнение n кол-во progressbar'ов в WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2017

Есть элемент icTodoList, который нужно заполнить progressbar'ми на каждого человека. Можно ли вообще такое реализовать с помощью цикла и \n? Выше представлены мои попытки написания кода. Но icTodoList выводит только один progressbar на первого человека

```
for (int countCall = 1; countCall <= allShooters; countCall++)
{
            int randomValue = randomValues.Next(1, totalHits + 1);
            progressHits.Maximum = totalHits;
            progressPercents.Value = 100;
            countHits.Content += "" + randomValue + "\n";
            countPercent.Content += "" + Math.Round(1.0 * randomValue / totalHits * 100, 2) + "\n";
            countRandom += randomValue;
            averagePercent += Math.Round(1.0 * randomValue / totalHits * 100, 2);
            outaverageHits.Content = "Среднее значение попаданий \n" + Math.Round((double)countRandom / countCall, 2) + "\n";
            outaveragePercents.Content = "Среднее значение процентов \n" + Math.Round((double)averagePercent / countCall, 2) + "\n";
            progressHits.Value = (double)countRandom / countCall;
            progressPercents.Value = (double)averagePercent / countCall;

            items.Add(new TodoItem() { Completion = averagePercent});
            icTodoList.ItemsSource = items;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поставьте точку останова на `icTodoList.ItemsSource = items;` проверьте значения у `items` у `allShooters` и `countCall`. Значения соответствуют вашим ожиданиям?

Comment: Да, все значения правильны